# How can I parse a Google public Calendar in android?

Tags: java, android, google-calendar-api, google-data-api

I have a Google Calendar in a website that is available to everyone. I want to parse this calendar and display it in an Android app.

I understand I have to use the Google Data API [google-api-java-client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Android), but that's as far as I have gotten. Can anyone explain or give me links to tutorials or documents that might be helpful

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can get more answers if you try something first and then post your results asking more specific questions. Good luck!

Comment: @KevinBedell I agree, but I need to start somewhere that's why I asked for some tutorials, but dont worry I will update the quetion as I go along. Also, I found that I need to to get event Ids and calendar ids in order to make requests to the Google servers, I have got the Calendar id but how do i get the events ids?

Comment: Hi there, have you found good examples and/or tutorials? I'm stuck at the same problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/calendar/v3/) is the correct documentation you're looking for.